# Vue2.0 Encounter push undefined occurs during router.push

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I'm working on a project which is trying to implement a function route on the list of subMenu display on by the mainMenu. Each subMenu has their own specific name which I want to append and route based on the name of the subMenu to the `route.path` that I wanna achieve.

Template

```
<li v-for='child in item.children'>
   <a href="#"  v-on:click.prevent="navigate(child.text)">{{child.text}}</a>
   <!--<router-view v-bind:to="'/trafficSetting/' + child.text">{{ child.text }}</router-view>-->
</li>
```

Script

```
navigate (to) {
  alert(to)
  this.$router.push(to)
}
```

Main.JS

```
Vue.use(VueRouter)
Vue.use(VueResource)
// Vue.use(MintUI)
// define routes
const Home = resolve => require(['./components/home.vue'], resolve)
const trafficSetting = resolve => require(['./components/trafficSetting.vue'], resolve)
const seedResourcesManagement = resolve => require(['./components/seedResourcesManagement.vue'], resolve)
const driverUserManagement = resolve => require(['./components/driverUserManagement.vue'], resolve)
const whiteblackListManagement = resolve => require(['./components/whiteblackListManagement.vue'], resolve)
const VPNserverManagement = resolve => require(['./components/VPNserverManagement.vue'], resolve)
const routes = [
    {path: '/', component: Home},
    {path: '/trafficSetting', name:'trafficS', component: trafficSetting},
    {path: '/seedResourcesManagement', component: seedResourcesManagement},
    {path: '/driverUserManagement', component: driverUserManagement},
    {path: '/whiteblackListManagement', component: whiteblackListManagement},
    {path: '/VPNserverManagement', component: VPNserverManagement}
]
```

This results in

> `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You are not declaring the router so try this:

```
   const router = new VueRouter({
        routes = [
            {path: '/', component: Home},
            {path: '/trafficSetting', name:'trafficS', component: trafficSetting},
            {path: '/seedResourcesManagement', component: seedResourcesManagement},
            {path: '/driverUserManagement', component: driverUserManagement},
            {path: '/whiteblackListManagement', component: whiteblackListManagement},
            {path: '/VPNserverManagement', component: VPNserverManagement}
        ]
    })
```

Comment: indeed im setting the router const but after i push the router seems nothing happen

Comment: Can you edit your question and show more information to see the `data` and `methods` declarations in the component and the full content of main.js? It's working the `alert(to)` on navigate function? Have you add `router` inside vue component like: `const app = new Vue({ router}).$mount('#app')`